# How do I code this task to now have exception, so it returns the file in container?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, task, azure-blob-storage

I Just put the code below in a new .net6.0 top level statement "program.cs" (Console app)

How can I code this to avoid the following exception:
"***System.InvalidOperationException:
'A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).'***"

```
var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new UriBuilder("someUrl").Uri);
var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("somefile.txt");

using var stream = blockBlobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true);
```

Addition1:
[image]

Comment: Just try to await the execution of your async task.

Comment: If i do that the error is as stated in Addition1, and it doesnt solve it.

Comment: Please do not post code or exceptions as images.

Comment: Please also show more of your code

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results**

I executed the same code in my environment and got same error:

**Response:**

[image]

When I tried with async and await method and got successfully overwritten a file:
**code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized;


namespace azuretask
{
   class program {
 
            static async Task Main()
            {
                var blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new UriBuilder("storage container url with sas ").Uri);
                var blockBlobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlockBlobClient("ACL.txt");
                using var stream = await blockBlobClient.OpenWriteAsync(true);
            }

    }
}
```

**Response:**
[image]

Make sure with **`URL`** as proper permission :
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]